# change css of div from variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to add style to a div using a JS variable: `g_heightOfKildareImage`?

For example in C# it would look like:

```
<div id="ButtonsDiv" class="storyBoardButtons" style="bottom:" + g_heightOfKildareImage + "" />
```

Comment: Why you do not use `document.getElementById("ButtonsDiv").style.bottom = g_heightOfKildareImage`.

Comment: yes I am using that I was just curious as to is this possible. thanks though

Comment: `asp.net-mvc3` tag is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

here you can do

```
<div id="ButtonsDiv" class="storyBoardButtons" style='<%Response.Write("bottom:" + g_heightOfKildareImage); %>' />
```

Comment: OP is asking how to do it in JS, not C#.